# PyCharm formatting adds mixture of tabs and spaces on line wrap

Tags: python, format, pycharm, code-formatting

I am using PyCharm IDE for python coding. I prefer to use tabs over spaces for indentation. I've changed the setting accordingly in python. Also, since Python gives a warning if a line exceeds 120 characters, I've added hard-wrap also. Now, if some line exceeds 120 characters, when I do code-reformat, PyCharm moves it to next line which is absolutely fine. But what it does while moving it to next line is it adds a mixture of tabs and spaces in the indentation.

To be a bit more specific, suppose the code is at an indentation level of 3 tabs and the line exceeds 120 character limit. So, while reformatting, it moves a part of the code to next line. This line has indentation consisting of 6 tabs and 2 spaces. Now, again PyCharm gives a warning that indentation is mixture of tabs and spaces.

How to solve this problem?
I know I can ignore that warning or disable 120 character limit or use spaces instead of tabs. But I don't want to do them. I'm used to those settings. I want to know how to fix PyCharm so that it uses only tabs and no spaces.

Thank you!